# How to get jQuery alert to display when radio button isn't selected?

Tags: jquery

I have a web page that displays a series of multiple choice questions. The user answers each question by selecting a radio button. They then click a button to load the next question, etc.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="questionWrapper">
    <div class="question">
        <h1>Question 1</h1>
        <div class="funkyradio">
            <div class="funkyradio-success">
                <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio1" />
                <label for="radio1">Answer 1</label>
            </div>
            <div class="funkyradio-success">
                <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio2" />
                <label for="radio2">Answer 2</label>
            </div>
            <div class="funkyradio-success">
                <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio3" />
                <label for="radio3">Answer 3</label>
            </div>
            <div class="funkyradio-success">
                <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio4" />
                <label for="radio4">Answer 4</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="answer" href="#">CLICK HERE TO GO TO NEXT QUESTION</a>
    </div>
    <div class="question">
        <h1>Question 2</h1>
        <div class="funkyradio">
            <div class="funkyradio-success">
                <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio5" />
                <label for="radio5">Answer 1</label>
            </div>
            <div class="funkyradio-success">
                <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio6" />
                <label for="radio6">Answer 2</label>
            </div>
            <div class="funkyradio-success">
                <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio7" />
                <label for="radio7">Answer 3</label>
            </div>
            <div class="funkyradio-success">
                <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio8" />
                <label for="radio8">Answer 4</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="answer" href="#">CLICK HERE TO GO TO NEXT QUESTION</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

...and here's the jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $("#questionWrapper .question").first().show(), $("#questionWrapper .answer").click(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault(), $("input:radio").is(':checked') ?
                        ($(this).parents(".question").fadeOut(200), $(this).parents().next(".question").length &&
                            $(this).parents().next(".question").delay(200).fadeIn()) : alert("Sorry, you need to select an 
                            answer before continuing.
                            ")
                        })
            });
```

When a user clicks on the button without first selecting an answer, an alert is supposed to be displayed. However, it only works on the first question.

How can I get it to work on each of the questions?

I thought I could change `$("input:radio").is(':checked')` to `$(this).parents(".question input:radio").is(':checked')` but then the alert is triggered whether or not an answer is selected.

Comment: Please include all relevant code **in the question itself**, preferably as a [MCVE]. Please make it as easy as possible for use to help you by **not** making us to go off site to find important information , like your HTML context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tip 1, make your code easier to read. Throwing all this onto 5 lines makes it difficult to debug.

Next you want to check against the number of checked fields in the parent.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#questionWrapper .question").first().show();
  $("#questionWrapper .answer").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    let $parent = $(this).parents(".question");
    //Check the number of selected radio in the parent    
    if($($parent).find("input:radio:checked").length > 0) {
      $($parent).fadeOut(200);
      
      if($($parent).next(".question").length) { 
         $($parent).next(".question").delay(200).fadeIn()
      }
    } else {alert("Sorry, you need to select an answer before continuing.");}
  })
});
```

```css
img,
legend {
  border: 0
}

body,
figure {
  margin: 0
}

body,
mark {
  color: #000
}

.answer,
.centerIt {
  text-align: center
}

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
main,
nav,
section,
summary {
  display: block
}

audio,
canvas,
video {
  display: inline-block
}

audio:not([controls]) {
  display: none;
  height: 0
}

[hidden],
template {
  display: none
}

html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  height: 100%
}

a {
  background: 0 0
}

a:focus {
  outline: dotted thin
}

a:active,
a:hover {
  outline: 0
}

abbr[title] {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted
}

b,
strong {
  font-weight: 700
}

dfn {
  font-style: italic
}

hr {
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  height: 0
}

mark {
  background: #ff0
}

code,
kbd,
pre,
samp {
  font-family: monospace, serif;
  font-size: 1em
}

pre {
  white-space: pre-wrap
}

q {
  quotes: "\201C" "\201D" "\2018" "\2019"
}

small {
  font-size: 80%
}

sub,
sup {
  font-size: 75%;
  line-height: 0;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: baseline
}

sup {
  top: -.5em
}

sub {
  bottom: -.25em
}

svg:not(:root) {
  overflow: hidden
}

.checkItem,
textarea {
  overflow: auto
}

fieldset {
  border: 1px solid silver;
  margin: 0 2px;
  padding: .35em .625em .75em
}

legend {
  padding: 0
}

button,
input,
select,
textarea {
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 100%;
  margin: 0
}

button,
input {
  line-height: normal
}

button,
select {
  text-transform: none
}

button,
html input[type=button],
input[type=reset],
input[type=submit] {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  cursor: pointer
}

button[disabled],
html input[disabled] {
  cursor: default
}

.answer,
.name,
.profile {
  cursor: pointer
}

input[type=checkbox],
input[type=radio] {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0
}

input[type=search] {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box
}

input[type=search]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
input[type=search]::-webkit-search-decoration {
  -webkit-appearance: none
}

button::-moz-focus-inner,
input::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0
}

textarea {
  vertical-align: top
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0
}

body {
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px
}

#wrapper {
  max-width: 640px;
  margin: 0 auto
}

.topLegal {
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 3px auto
}

#questionWrapper {
  padding: 15px
}

.main-content {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #FFF!important;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px
}

.main-content p {
  font-size: 13px
}

.main-content h1 {
  font-size: 20px
}

.header,
.prize-date {
  font-size: 18px
}

.main-content h2 {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400
}

hr {
  border: 1px solid #FFF;
  color: #FFF;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

.comments {
  background-color: #eeeff4;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #FFF;
  padding: 10px
}

.profile {
  float: left;
  width: 60px;
  margin-right: 10px
}

.comment-content img,
.profile img {
  width: 100%
}

.name {
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #3b5998;
  margin: 0
}

.comment-content {
  float: left;
  width: 190px
}

.clr {
  clear: both
}

.header {
  margin: 20px auto
}

.header b {
  color: #9a794a
}

span.color {
  color: red
}

.intro {
  font-size: 15px
}

.giftcard {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto
}


/*---<<<EDIT BUTTONS HERE>>>---*/

.answer {
  background-color: #146f40;
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 8px 0;
  margin: 8px 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 6px
}


/*---<<<EDIT BUTTONS HERE>>>---*/

.answer:hover {
  opacity: .8
}

.answer:active {
  position: relative;
  top: 1px
}

.btnYes {
  color: #fff;
  background: #00AF00;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #080
}

.btnNo {
  color: #fff;
  background: #D62A14;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #A2200F
}

.check,
.question,
.result {
  display: none
}

.checkItem,
img.loader {
  clear: both;
  display: block
}

.lastMargin {
  height: 5px
}

img.loader {
  margin: 5px 0 15px 5px
}

.check {
  clear: both
}

.checkItem img {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px
}

.checkItem h3 {
  float: left;
  margin: 0
}

.centerIt {
  margin: 125px auto 0
}

.centerIt a {
  margin: 0 auto
}

.overlay-checker {
  display: none;
  background: #000;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: 700
}

.overlay-checker-points {
  max-width: 700px;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 0
}

.overlay-checker-points li {
  list-style: none
}

.overlay-checker-points li img {
  height: 21px
}

.terms {
  font-size: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0
}

.footer .footer-container {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px !important;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  color: #888888;
}

.footer-container .footer-menu a {
  font-size: 14px !important;
  color: #888888;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.footer-container .footer-menu a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.funkyradio div {
  clear: both;
  /*margin: 0 50px;*/
  overflow: hidden;
}

.funkyradio label {
  /*min-width: 400px;*/
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #D1D3D4;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.funkyradio input[type="radio"]:empty,
.funkyradio input[type="checkbox"]:empty {
  display: none;
}

.funkyradio input[type="radio"]:empty~label,
.funkyradio input[type="checkbox"]:empty~label {
  position: relative;
  line-height: 2.5em;
  text-indent: 3.25em;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.funkyradio input[type="radio"]:empty~label:before,
.funkyradio input[type="checkbox"]:empty~label:before {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: '';
  width: 2.5em;
  background: #D1D3D4;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

.funkyradio input[type="radio"]:hover:not(:checked)~label:before,
.funkyradio input[type="checkbox"]:hover:not(:checked)~label:before {
  content: '\2714';
  text-indent: .9em;
  color: #C2C2C2;
}

.funkyradio input[type="radio"]:hover:not(:checked)~label,
.funkyradio input[type="checkbox"]:hover:not(:checked)~label {
  color: #888;
}

.funkyradio input[type="radio"]:checked~label:before,
.funkyradio input[type="checkbox"]:checked~label:before {
  content: '\2714';
  text-indent: .9em;
  color: #333;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.funkyradio input[type="radio"]:checked~label,
.funkyradio input[type="checkbox"]:checked~label {
  color: #777;
}

.funkyradio input[type="radio"]:focus~label:before,
.funkyradio input[type="checkbox"]:focus~label:before {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #999;
}

.funkyradio-success input[type="radio"]:checked~label:before,
.funkyradio-success input[type="checkbox"]:checked~label:before {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #5cb85c;
}

.answer {
  text-decoration: none !important;
  color: #fff !important;
}

.answer:hover {
  text-decoration: none !important;
  color: #fff !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' id='bootstrap-stylesheet-css'  href='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css?ver=5.2.4' type='text/css' media='all' />
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="questionWrapper">
    <div class="question">
      <h1>Question 1</h1>
      <div class="funkyradio">
        <div class="funkyradio-success">
          <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio1" />
          <label for="radio1">Answer 1</label>
        </div>
        <div class="funkyradio-success">
          <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio2" />
          <label for="radio2">Answer 2</label>
        </div>
        <div class="funkyradio-success">
          <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio3" />
          <label for="radio3">Answer 3</label>
        </div>
        <div class="funkyradio-success">
          <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio4" />
          <label for="radio4">Answer 4</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="answer" href="#">CLICK HERE TO GO TO NEXT QUESTION</a>
    </div>
    <div class="question">
      <h1>Question 2</h1>
      <div class="funkyradio">
        <div class="funkyradio-success">
          <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio5" />
          <label for="radio5">Answer 1</label>
        </div>
        <div class="funkyradio-success">
          <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio6" />
          <label for="radio6">Answer 2</label>
        </div>
        <div class="funkyradio-success">
          <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio7" />
          <label for="radio7">Answer 3</label>
        </div>
        <div class="funkyradio-success">
          <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio8" />
          <label for="radio8">Answer 4</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="answer" href="#">CLICK HERE TO GO TO NEXT QUESTION</a>
    </div>
    <div class="question">
      <h1>Question 3</h1>
      <div class="funkyradio">
        <div class="funkyradio-success">
          <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio9" />
          <label for="radio9">Answer 1</label>
        </div>
        <div class="funkyradio-success">
          <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio10" />
          <label for="radio10">Answer 2</label>
        </div>
        <div class="funkyradio-success">
          <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio11" />
          <label for="radio11">Answer 3</label>
        </div>
        <div class="funkyradio-success">
          <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio12" />
          <label for="radio12">Answer 4</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="answer" href="#">NO MORE QUESTIONS</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No Prob, don't forget to accept the answer an upvote when you can.

Comment: I've accepted the answer and upvoted it but the vote isn't shown publicly as I don't have a high enough reputation.